# Read each line of XML file

Tags: powershell

I want to read each line of XML file in PowerShell script. after `Get-Content` of XML file, I used `foreach` statement to read each line element. and it wasn't working. How do I read each line of XML file?

`Test.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Install-Plan>
    <ADSetup> ... </ADSetup>
    <SQLSetup>
        <SqlServerName>ServerName</SqlServerName>
        <SqlVersion>SQL2014</SqlVersion>
        <InstanceName>MSSQLSERVER</InstanceName>
        <SqlInstall>TRUE</SqlInstall>
        <SqlClientInstall>TRUE</SqlClientInstall>
        <RSInstall>TRUE</RSInstall>
        ...
    </SQLSetup>
</Install-Plan>
```

PowerShell:

```bsh
[xml]$XmlData = Get-Content test.xml -ErrorAction Stop
$Config = $xmlData.SelectNodes("//Install-Plan");
$uConfigFile = $Config.CommonConfig.SQLSetup
foreach ($uconfigval in $uConfigFile) {
    switch ($uconfigval[0]) {
        "$SQLServerData.SQLSetup.Sqlserver"  {$uSQL_SERVER_NAME = $uconfigVal.Trim()}
        "$SQLServerData.SQLSetup.SqlVersion" {$uSQLVERSION = $uconfigVal[1].Trim()}
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very vague and contains no actual code so we have no idea what, or how, you are trying to do. You really need to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please add your codes here. Whatever you tried till now.

Comment: I am concerned about only SqlSetup section from xml and have read the same into an array variable and trying to do foreach into variable uconfigval from each line and assign into each variable.

Comment: Please *edit* the question with additional details. Comments are poorly suited to contain code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample XML you posted doesn't have a node `<CommonConfig>`, so `$uConfigFile = $Config.CommonConfig.SQLSetup` will produce an empty result. Also, the variable and conditions of your `switch` statement are completely off.

What you actually want to do is something like this:

```
foreach ($node in $xmlData.SelectNodes('/Install-Plan/SQLSetup/*')) {
    switch ($node.Name) {
        'SqlServerName' { $uSQL_SERVER_NAME = $node.InnerText.Trim() }
        'SqlVersion'    { $uSQLVERSION = $node.InnerText.Trim() }
        ...
    }
}
```

or (perhaps better) fill a hashtable rather than individual variables:

```
$cfg = @{}
foreach ($node in $xmlData.SelectNodes('/Install-Plan/SQLSetup/*')) {
    $cfg[$node.Name] = $node.InnerText.Trim()
}
```